# Let $G$ be abelian, $H$ and $K$ subgroups of orders $n$, $m$. Then G has subgroup of order $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be abelian, $H$ and $K$ subgroups of orders $n$, $m$. Then G
>   has subgroup of order $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$.

This is a statement that my lecturer mentioned in my (beginners') Abstract Algebra class. I'm not sure I understand why it's true.

What I have so far: Use the abelian group structure theorem on $\langle H, K\rangle$ (finite group generated by $H$ and $K$). Then $\langle H,K\rangle=C_{a_1}C_{a_2}\dotsm$ and $n, m |\langle H,K\rangle$. Which means it's also true that $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)|\langle H,K\rangle$. Can I leverage this to say there's a subgroup of order $\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$?

Comment: Counterexample to the title: Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, $H=\{0\}$, $K=\{0,5\}$

Comment: @Amr What do you mean? $|H|=1$, so $K$ is a subgroup of order $\operatorname{lcm}(|H|,|K|)$.

Comment: @Amr I don't see the problem - $K$ is a subgroup of order $2=\operatorname{lcm}(1,2)$.

Comment: @Matt Pressland  I am sorry. I thought the title said "...., then $G$ has order $lcm(m,n)$"

Comment: Oops, I left a comment/flag saying this question is a duplicate of something it is not a duplicate of.

Comment: I take it we are assuming $G$ is finite. If so, that structure theorem can be used to show that $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$ for every $d$ dividing the order of $G$. Now it's immediate; if $m$ and $n$ divide some number, then so does their lcm.

Comment: One can also show that any finite abelian group has elements of all orders dividing the order of the group using much less than the structure theorem (just the abelian version of Cauchy plus induction). However, this is a classic exercise meant to be solved with even less than that (originally stated to be solved even before introducing homomorphisms, and it took decades for a solution to be found using only the very basics).

Comment: @Tobias: "any finite abelian group has elements of all orders dividing the order of the group" is only true for cyclic groups, of course.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ahh, woops. I meant subgroups rather than elements. Silly mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If an abelian group has subgroups of orders $m$ and $n$, respectively, then it has a subgroup whose order is $\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765522/if-an-abelian-group-has-subgroups-of-orders-m-and-n-respectively-then-it-h)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $|H\cap K|$ divides $|H|$ and $|K|$, it divides ${\rm gcd} (|H|,|K|)$, so ${\rm gcd} (|H|,|K|)=a|H\cap K|$ for some integer $a$. Further, 
$$
|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{|H||K|a}{{\rm gcd} (|H|,|K|)}={\rm lcm} (|H|,|K|)a.
$$
Now one must use the assertion: if $G$ is abelian and $n$ divides $|G|$ then $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$. Therefore $HK$ has a subgroup of order ${\rm lcm} (|H|,|K|)$.

Comment: Easier: $H$ is a subgroup of $HK$, hence $|H|$ divides $|HK|$, and likewise $|K|$ divides it, hence also $\mathrm{lcm}(|H|,|K|)$ divides it.

Comment: @Martin Brandenburg: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Or perhaps use my comment on the question.

Comment: @Gerry How exactly would you use the structure theorem?

Comment: @Leo, too long for a comment. Post it as a question, and someone will show you how to do it.

Comment: @Gerry Will do.

Comment: @Gerry: Your proof only works when $G$ is finite. Note that Boris' proof also works when $G$ is infinite. Actually Boris' proof reduces to the finite case by considerung $HK$.

Comment: @Leo: It suffices to consider finite abelian $p$-groups. These are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k_1} \oplus \dotsc \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p^{k_s}$ for some natural numbers $k_1 \leq \dotsc \leq k_s$. Every divisor of the order $p^{k_1+\dotsc+k_s}$ has the form $p^{k'_1+\dotsc+k'_s}$ for some $k'_i \leq k_s$. Now it is easy to write down a subgroup of this order.

Comment: Since $\langle H,K \rangle$ is finite, and we can assume that $G = \langle H,K \rangle$, there is no need to assume that $G$ is finite. (In other words, we don't need to assume it because we can assume it!)