# Subgroups of abelian groups of order multiple of 4

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Why the following assertion is false?

> Every abelian group of order divisible by $4$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order 4.

If the group is abelian (i.e. cyclic), then we know that cyclic groups has cyclic subgroups. I cannot see why this assertion must be false.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem only tells us that the order of a subgroup must divide the order of a group. It doesn't say anything about the existence of such subgroups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cyclic Subgroups of Abelian Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340182/cyclic-subgroups-of-abelian-groups)

Answer (score 2):

The group $\mathbb {Z}_2 \times \mathbb {Z}_2$ is not cyclic, and has order 4.

Also, Lagrange's theorem doesnt tell us anything about the existence of a subgroup of order 4.

Comment: Yes, but it is also not abelian, so it does not enter in the conditions of the statement.

Comment: It is abelian. Every group of order $p²$ with $p$ prime is abelian.

Comment: See for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443642/prove-that-every-group-of-order-4-is-abelian

Comment: The smallest nonabelian group has six elements.

Comment: My mistake, Klein group is only no-cyclic.